# Stationary distribution of AR(1) processes and Lyapunov central limit theorem

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian, time-series

Let $X_t$ follow the following AR(1) process:
$$
X_t=\rho X_{t-1}+e_t
$$
in which $|\rho|<1$ and $e_t$ is iid noise term with density $f$, mean $0$ and finite moments up to a certain order.

I am trying to look for general characterization of the stationary distribution of the process as a function of the density $f$. In the process, I come across Lyapunov's central limit theorem. It seems that I can write
$$
Y_t=e_t+\rho e_{t-1}+\rho^2 e_{t-2}+...
$$
and $Y_t$ will converge to the stationary distribution. But then it seems that as long as $f$ satisfies the Lyapunov condition, $Y_t$ would always converge to some Gaussian distribution due to Lyapunov's central limit theorem.

Now I am confused. It seems that no matter what $f$ is, the stationary distribution is always Gaussian. This cannot be right, since there is a whole literature of how to generate stationary non-Gaussian autoregressive processes...Please help me find where I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean here by the Lyapunov condition?

Comment: The Lyapunov condition can be found in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447518/intuitive-explanation-of-lyapunov-condition-for-clt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $Y_t$ is a random variable (r.v.) and therefore cannot converge to any distribution. Only a family of distributions can converge to a distribution.
2. The distribution of $Y_t$ does not depend on $t$, because the joint distribution of the sequence $(e_t,e_{t-1},\dots)$ does not depend on $t$. So, it does not make much sense to talk about the convergence of the distribution of $Y_t$.
3. By Cramér's decomposition theorem (see e.g. the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_decomposition_theorem) or [Section 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.01768)), the distribution of $Y_t$ will be Gaussian if and only if the distribution of each $e_t$ is Gaussian. Indeed, $Y_t$ is the sum of independent r.v.'s $e_t$ and $\rho e_{t-1}+\rho^2 e_{t-2}+\cdots$. So, if $Y_t$ is Gaussian, then $e_t$ is Gaussian.

That $Y_t$ is not Gaussian in general follows from the following, much more elementary argument: Suppose that $|e_t|\le1$ almost surely (a.s.). Then
$$|Y_t|\le|e_t|+|\rho|\, |e_{t-1}|+|\rho|^2 |e_{t-2}|+\cdots \\
\le1+|\rho|+|\rho|^2+\cdots=\frac1{1-|\rho|}$$
a.s. So, the r.v. $Y_t$ is a.s. bounded and therefore not Gaussian.

Comment: I understand where I went wrong. $e_0 + \rho e_1+...$ and $Y_t$ are completely different objects.